# How to use netbeans Source view and still use my own paint() method

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, paint

i stumbled upon a small problem. I designed some elements in my JFrame using netbeans Source view, and now i want to paint some elements(etc. circles). I know its done using the paint() method where i do graphics.draw(circle) etc., but that overrides the paint() method generated by netbeans and none of the elements i styled using source view is now shown. Can it be done so that i can use both Source view and my own paint method? or do i need to create everything manually and paint it on my own?

Comment: Don't paint directly on the JFrame. Instead paint in the `paintComponent(...) method of a JPanel or other class descending from JComponent.

Comment: oh right, that could work...i will try thanks

Answer (score 0):

call super.paint() in your paint() mehod
or if it doesnt work call paintComponent() method of the container